# Android: Alert dialog throws exception inside socket thread

Tags: android

I am having the following Android code, where-in Android app contacts a Socket program and get result as "SUCCESS" in a thread model. After that, trying to show an alert dialog, but android program gets exception as `thread exiting with uncaught exception`
I couldn't get what's wrong here. Can't I show an alert inside a thread? Please advise.

```
public class RandomIDActivity extends Activity {

        ............. 

        clientthread = new ClientThread();

            Button connectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Thread t = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    t.start();
                }
            });

        }


class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // We got this IP from servlet and stored temporarily, so retrieve it from there.
            String socketServerIP = ((GlobalStore) RandomIDActivity.this.getApplication()).getSocketIPAddress();
            Log.d("socketServerIP", socketServerIP);

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(socketServerIP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                EditText randTxtField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                pw.println(randTxtField.getText().toString());
                //output.write(imgbyte,0,imgbyte.length);
                pw.flush();             

                // Read randrom ID returned by Socket
                BufferedReader socketReader;
                try {
                    socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    msgStr = socketReader.readLine();
                    Log.d("msgStr: ", msgStr);

                    if (msgStr.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS") )
                    {
                        socket.close();

                 // Crashing if I call alert dialog like this.
                        CobrowseAlertDialog("Successfully connected! Click OK to starts screen sharing!", true);

                        //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        //startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CobrowseAlertDialog("There seems to be problem in connecting..Try connecting it again with proper Random Auth ID!", false);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

         }
    }


    public void CobrowseAlertDialog(String msg, boolean bMove) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RandomIDActivity.this); // getParent()
            builder.setTitle("Cobrowsing")
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                    //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

    }
```

LogCat:

```
03-24 17:12:20.353: D/socketServerIP(32717): 192.168.1.21
03-24 17:12:20.503: D/msgStr:(32717): SUCCESS
03-24 17:12:29.952: W/dalvikvm(32717): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415efba8)
03-24 17:12:33.926: W/jdwp(32717): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
```

Comment: you can show alert dialog on main thread only. Post your logcat here

Comment: you are invoking dialog from the main thread which is not good as a practice, please read the answer given at answer section!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android , Thread is not directly update UI thread. If u want to update ur UI , u should use

Handler.

```
 Handler mHandler;

     @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // We got this IP from servlet and stored temporarily, so retrieve it from there.
        String socketServerIP = ((GlobalStore) RandomIDActivity.this.getApplication()).getSocketIPAddress();
        Log.d("socketServerIP", socketServerIP);

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(socketServerIP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            EditText randTxtField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            pw.println(randTxtField.getText().toString());
            //output.write(imgbyte,0,imgbyte.length);
            pw.flush();             

            // Read randrom ID returned by Socket
            BufferedReader socketReader;
            try {
                socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                msgStr = socketReader.readLine();
                Log.d("msgStr: ", msgStr);

  //add handler here
   mHandler.post(new Runnable{
public void run(){
   if (msgStr.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS") )
                {
                    socket.close();

             // Crashing if I call alert dialog like this.
                    CobrowseAlertDialog("Successfully connected! Click OK to starts screen sharing!", true);

                    //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    CobrowseAlertDialog("There seems to be problem in connecting..Try connecting it again with proper Random Auth ID!", false);
                }
        }
   });





            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: Same issue has observed even after adding handler code like that.

Comment: Hi, It worked nicely! Thank you. One more issue in the same flow, In the "CobrowseAlertDialog" method, when i add code for moving to next view using this->  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);  throws Fatal exception as thread exiting with uncaught exception. What could be the reason? Please advise.

Comment: i think context should not be used on alertbox. pls wirte a method as

Comment: example(){Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); startActivity(intent);} and call them inside alertbox.

Comment: It is working fine, i added "final Context context = RandomIDActivity.this;". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Background threads cannot pop up dialogs. What you can do is , you can work with some  **Handler** on your UI thread to pop up the dialog box appearance.

else one alternative is also available but not so good and not great to recommened

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
////code for alert dialog
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In android , Thread is not directly update UI thread. If u want to update ur UI , u should use

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

```
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // We got this IP from servlet and stored temporarily, so retrieve it from there.
        String socketServerIP = ((GlobalStore) RandomIDActivity.this.getApplication()).getSocketIPAddress();
        Log.d("socketServerIP", socketServerIP);

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(socketServerIP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            EditText randTxtField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            pw.println(randTxtField.getText().toString());
            //output.write(imgbyte,0,imgbyte.length);
            pw.flush();             

            // Read randrom ID returned by Socket
            BufferedReader socketReader;
            try {
                socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                msgStr = socketReader.readLine();
                Log.d("msgStr: ", msgStr);

                if (msgStr.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS") )
                {
                    socket.close();

             // Crashing if I call alert dialog like this.
                    CobrowseAlertDialog("Successfully connected! Click OK to starts screen sharing!", true);

                    //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    CobrowseAlertDialog("There seems to be problem in connecting..Try connecting it again with proper Random Auth ID!", false);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
}
```

Handler handler=new  Handler();

Button connectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              handler.post(new  Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // We got this IP from servlet and stored temporarily, so retrieve it from there.
        String socketServerIP = ((GlobalStore) RandomIDActivity.this.getApplication()).getSocketIPAddress();
        Log.d("socketServerIP", socketServerIP);

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(socketServerIP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            EditText randTxtField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            pw.println(randTxtField.getText().toString());
            //output.write(imgbyte,0,imgbyte.length);
            pw.flush();             

            // Read randrom ID returned by Socket
            BufferedReader socketReader;
            try {
                socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                msgStr = socketReader.readLine();
                Log.d("msgStr: ", msgStr);

                if (msgStr.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS") )
                {
                    socket.close();

             // Crashing if I call alert dialog like this.
                    CobrowseAlertDialog("Successfully connected! Click OK to starts screen sharing!", true);

                    //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    CobrowseAlertDialog("There seems to be problem in connecting..Try connecting it again with proper Random Auth ID!", false);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
}
```

);
                }
            });

Comment: Its not working, its failing at this line itself with exception, socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

Comment: But, One more issue in the same flow, In the "CobrowseAlertDialog" method, when i add code for moving to next view using this->  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);  throws Fatal exception as thread exiting with uncaught exception. What could be the reason? Please advise.